# The account is locked for user (HTTP 401) : Devstack installation Openstack

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openstack, ubuntu-18.04, user-accounts, devstack

I am installing openstack on a new server using devstack. I am having this error no matter the type of installation i do. I am installing on the host computer. I tried the exact same installation on another computer and it's fine and the openstack is working, however i kept on having this error on this cpu. I even formatted the computer and reinstalled the ubuntu 16 and 18 and, but whenever i tried to install openstack i kept on having this error. I haven't seen this type of error before and I don't know why the error is there, is it from the OS, the CPU or openstack. I tried different branches, rocky, stein, train or queens. its always the same. I tried this installation on another computer and it worked fine [image]

The world dump file can be found here [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lDYMA26Ss0sPKmAVHv_7xtha_wxAnbvv)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty tricky, I guess i used the same wifi adapter with my previous openstack cpu, so the ip address are the same. However i changed the password, so, openstack feels like the account for the ip address exist but the password is different. so it couldn't authenticate some keystone commands and it's failing. 
So here is how is discovered the problem, i tested the installation with a static ip, via an ethernet cable, and i discovered the error wasn't there. Then i realized that the host IP address that is used in this server is the same as the previous server. Interesting, So I connected back to the wifi adapter, the same IP address, and i used the same password as the previous cpu. and it worked fine, Installation went through ... Lol, i battled this for more than 3 days, very tricky.